# Ordering issue in modal window

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I have a problem with a component that loads in to a *modal* window. I am using the Alpha User Points system and it has a component that gives you a full list of yous site's users. It also gives you the ability to `order by username, by points etc`. If I use it outside of modal window it works fine. If I use it in to modal window, ordering don't work!!! When I put my mouse over table's headers, outside of modal window gives this...`javascript:tableOrdering('aup.referreid','asc','');`In to modal window I see this...`javascript:tableOrdering('aup.referreid','asc','');?ml=1` Using Firebug, I remove this `?ml=1` and it works into modal also!!! So the question is, why in to modal window gives this `?ml=1`, what is this? And how will I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here is the answer... I use the **Modalizer** extension of **nonumber.nl**. I was loading my component through modalizer's modal box, this is why I had this issue. So, if anyone use **Modalizer** to popup components and have the same problem with me, just go to modalizer's **Plugin Manager**, find the option **Convert Links inside Window** and disable it!!! But, after this, if you want to add link in to modal window and you don't want to show-up the whole front page but only the component or what ever this is, you have to add at the end of the link this **&ml=1**.